# PerspectiveCamera WPF looking downwards

Tags: wpf, 3d, perspectivecamera

I'm really getting frustrated of the perspectivecamera in WPF it does all kinds of strange things and all the solutions that I can find on the internet are not working for me.

Currently I have this code:

```
<Window x:Class="projectv1.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="MainWin">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1" >
        <Viewport3D.Camera>

            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain"  Position="-500 -10 300" LookDirection="0 -0.2 -1" UpDirection="0 1 0" FarPlaneDistance="10000" NearPlaneDistance="1" />

        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                </DirectionalLight>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>

        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                            Positions="-800,0,-1000 -200,0,-1000 -500,0,-100"
                            TriangleIndices="0,1,2" >
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>

</Grid>
```

So I have a triangle and I look at it from below... but now I want to look at it from the top so I changed the position of the Y parameter of the camera to any a value greater than 0 but then suddenly I cannot see anything. e.g. Position ="-500 -1 300" works but Position="-500 1 300" does not work anymore. I played a lot with the updirection variable but I was not able to fix this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `LookDirection` as well as the position.

What you have done is move the camera from one side of the object to the other, but kept it looking in the same direction:

```
----- <-- object

  ^
  |
  Camera
```

Like this:

```
  ^
  |
  Camera

----- <-- object
```

If you flip the camera direction as well you'll get the right result:

```
  Camera
  |
  V

----- <-- object
```

Comment: I thanks for the answer

I see what you mean but there are still some strange phenomena:
<PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain"  Position="-500 -1.0 0.0" LookDirection="0.0 -0.2 -1.0" UpDirection="0 1 0" FarPlaneDistance="10000" NearPlaneDistance="1" />

This works and I see the triangle completely on the top of my screen so when I change the Y position of the camera to 1.0 you would expect to see the triangle on the bottom of the screen right? but that doesnt happen

Comment: hmm this problem is still not fixt, I still have the same problem as I mentioned in my previous comment. Intuitively when I change the perspective camera settings to Position="-500 1.0 -300" LookDirection="0.001 -1.0 0.0001" I should see a part of the triangle but I cannot see anything....

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the order of the indices of your triangle. Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23332/WPF-3D-Primer , more specifically "step 4".

In short, the order in which you define the vertices also defines the direction from which the triangle is visible. The backside of the triangle is invisible.